# multi labels cytoscape js

Tags: jquery, qtip, qtip2, cytoscape.js

I'd like use two labels per node using cytoscape.js. One inside and another outside of the node, like this link image http://gcuculi.com/imagens/labels-constelation.png.

I used qtip for external labels, but I need to print (ctrl+p) this page and qtip div positions are absolute (from document), so they don't appear in right place.

There is a way to modify cytoscape.js for two labels or how I prevent qtip from 
this behavior?

Tks!!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure you can edit your cytoscape.js to do so. You only have to know where you'll put this information, so you probably will need a custom data field to storage the internal label, and show it in the proper position when editing cytoscape.js

Comment: Nice! The script uses "content" for node labels. I'm trying to create something like this "aux-content" and for positions "aux-text-valign" and "aux-text-halign".

Comment: hi @gcuculi can you share a sample code about it, I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to get multiple distinct labels is to use [compound nodes](http://js.cytoscape.org/#notation/compound-nodes), i.e. nodes that contain other nodes via a parent-child relationship.

If you gave every node its own parent node, you could provide different labels for the child and parent nodes and they would always appear together.

Node definitions with this representation might look like this:

```js
[
  { data: { id: 'childId', parent: 'parentId' } },
  { data: { id: 'parentId' } }
]
```