# Cytoscape Can't see parent node

Tags: javascript, html, cytoscape.js

I am having trying to put my parent node label in the middle of my Cytoscape.js node, but unfortunately I cannot see the label at all.

I can see the child label fine, but I am wondering if the parent label is hidden somewhere. My code is below.

```
var parentNode = currentNode + ',parent';
cy.add({group: 'nodes', data: { id: parentNode}});
cy.add({group: 'nodes', data: { id: currentNode, parent: parentNode }});
var eleParent = cy.getElementById(parentNode);
eleParent.css({'label': costLabel.toString(), 'text-valign' : 'center', 'text-halign' : 'center', color:'blue'});
var ele = cy.getElementById(currentNode);
ele.css({'label': ele.id().toString()});
```

I'm sure I am missing something very obvious here. I have used this stack overflow link as guidance - [multi labels cytoscape js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831483/multi-labels-cytoscape-js)

Thanks in advance, 
Jack

Answer (score 0):

You can simply look at cytocapes compound node:

https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/compound-nodes

Declaring the css of nodes is not necessary if you define that at the initialization of cytoscape. If you use compound nodes you get labels simply by typing:

```
'content': 'data(id)' // id should be a real id or a distinctive name.
```

when you are at the style init.

Instead of adding each node one by one you can add all at once, that would be much faster.

If you want to have a label be more visible, take a look at cytoscapes tutorial on labels:
http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/labels/

The code for this demo is here: 
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/documentation/demos/labels/code.js

Comment: I have fixed this now thank you though. Do you know how to make edges opaque without changing the opacity of the edge labels?

Comment: What do you mean by opaque? Do you want the label to be opaque or the backgroud of it? Opaque means that you can't see through it, right? If that is what you want you can add a class to your edge/node. Writing: classes: 'background' or classes: 'outline' gives the labels a box around them. I added the articles I know in my answer.